# Pagy gem: placement of UI widget is breaking pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Pagy gem for pagination in my rails 5 project. Pagination itself works fine, but when I add a UI widget (provided by pagy: pagy_items_selector(@pagy)) above pagination(pagy_nav(@pagy)) chunk in my view file, it's breaking the page links. Example: http://www.localhost:3000/articles?page=5&current_param=-pagy-2370055651028177601--items-

Instead if I place pagination(pagy_nav) above items selector (pagy_items_selector), the url is neat and works like a charm. Example: http://www.localhost:3000/articles?page=4&current_param=4

Here's my html code -

```html
<div class="items_per_page">
  <!-- Pagy UI widget for users to select items per page -->
  <%= pagy_items_selector(@pagy).html_safe %>
</div>

<!-- displaying a list of article titles -->
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center newsbox">
    <div class="article-content">
      <div class=" panel-title">
        <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<!--Pagy Nav links -->
<div class="pager">
  <!-- Pagination nav links -->
  <%= pagy_nav(@pagy).html_safe %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a Pagy bug [see #117](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy/issues/117). It has been fixed in Pagy version 1.3.1.

Updating your Gemfile should fix the problem:

```rb
bundle update pagy
```

If it doesn't, check the required gem in the Gemfile. It should be something like:

```rb
gem 'pagy', '~> 1.3` # or '1.3.1'
```

And update again.